# to show one to one function

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

how we can show f(x)=-x^2+6x-7 , if x is less than or equal 3 one to one??

DO we use a quadratic formula??

f(x)=-x^2+6x-7= 2-(x-3)^2.

f(x)=f(y) implies x=y which is injective or one to one.

f(x)=-x^2+6x-7=f(y)=-y^2+6y-7. I had skipped the work.
then we would get x(x-6)=y(y-6)  we could set x(x-6)=0 and y(y-6)=0. can we? if we can then, x-6=y-6. then x=y. Therefore, one to one.

any help would be appreciated. thank you!

Comment: What do you know about the shape of quadratic curves?

Answer (score 1):

Hints: Fill up details and provide explanations/proofs of the following

$$f(x)=f(y)\iff 2-(x-3)^2=2-(y-3)^2\iff (x-3)^2=(y-3)^2\iff$$

$$x-3=\pm(y-3)\iff\begin{cases}x=y&,\;\;\;\text{or}\\{}\\x+y=6\end{cases}$$

But if $\;x,y\le 3\;$ the second option above is impossible **unless** $\;x=y=3\;$ , so again equal...

Answer (score 0):

We can see that we have a negative quadratic,  so it has a global maximum,  to find it we take the first derivative and set it equal to zero and solve for $x$.

$f(x)=-x^2+6x-7\Rightarrow f'(x)=-2x+6=0\Rightarrow x=3$ also $f''(x)=-2\lt 0 $ so $x=3$ is a maximum, and here $f(3)=-3^2+6×3-7=-9+18-7=2$ so actually (if I've made no mistakes) $ f(x)\le 2 $.

So as x=3 is the maximum, due to symmetry,  taking $x\le 3 $ we get a one to one function.

Comment: could you show that function is one to one without taking derivative??